# Reading DataFrame from partitioned parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, apache-spark-sql

How to read partitioned parquet with condition as dataframe,

this works fine,

```
val dataframe = sqlContext.read.parquet("file:///home/msoproj/dev_data/dev_output/aln/partitions/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/day=25/*")
```

Partition is there for `day=1 to day=30` is it possible to read something like`(day = 5 to 6)` or `day=5,day=6`,

```
val dataframe = sqlContext.read.parquet("file:///home/msoproj/dev_data/dev_output/aln/partitions/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/day=??/*")
```

If I put `*` it gives me all 30 days data and it too big.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`sqlContext.read.parquet` can take multiple paths as input. If you want just `day=5` and `day=6`, you can simply add two paths like:

```
val dataframe = sqlContext
      .read.parquet("file:///your/path/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/day=5/", 
                    "file:///your/path/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/day=6/")
```

If you have folders under `day=X`, like say `country=XX`, `country` will automatically be added as a column in the `dataframe`.

> EDIT: As of Spark 1.6 one needs to provide a "basepath"-option in order for Spark to generate columns automatically. In Spark 1.6.x the above would have to be re-written like this to create a dataframe with the columns "data", "year", "month" and "day":

```
val dataframe = sqlContext
     .read
     .option("basePath", "file:///your/path/")
     .parquet("file:///your/path/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/day=5/", 
                    "file:///your/path/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/day=6/")
```

Comment: First thanks for response, I was looking for more simple way. In case some 20 days as subset this way will be kind of difficult. I would be filtering often to check the data accuracy.

Comment: Then why not simply do `val dataframe = sqlContext.read.parquet("file:///your/path/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/")? `day` is added as a column in the dataframe, which you can then filter on.

Comment: Actually, it very huge data running. Data is from 2007 to 2015. On an average 5 billion row of raw logs are processed and stored. I would be asked for particular data report on demand

Comment: Right, so the first thing you do is a `filter` operation. Since Spark does lazy evaluation you should have no problems with the size of the data set. The filter will be applied before any actions and only the data you are interested in will be kept in memory.

Comment: Well it seems only answer is this!

Comment: Have an upvote, Glennie! Your remark about using filter() on the read.parquet() was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glennie where did you read about the option on sqlcontext.read? I could not find anything in spark docs.

Comment: It is written in the documentation. Look [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery). When they changed it from the old way to the new way, I remember that I stubbled across it in the release notes.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt: i'm trying to read the AVRO files using Spark avro reader , i gave the basePath option but still the partition columns are not available in the DataFrame. any idea?

Comment: Is there a way to have wildcards in the `basePath` I seem to be getting error : `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Option 'basePath' must be a directory`

Comment: @samthebest did you got any solution of adding wildcards in basepath?

Answer (score 52):

If you want to read for multiple days, for example `day = 5` and `day = 6` and want to mention the range in the path itself, wildcards can be used:

```
val dataframe = sqlContext
  .read
  .parquet("file:///your/path/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/day={5,6}/*")
```

Wildcards can also be used to specify a range of days:

```
val dataframe = sqlContext
  .read
  .parquet("file:///your/path/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/day=[5-10]/*")
```

This matches all days from 5 to 10.

Comment: Is this exclusively for scala? I'm trying it with pyspark, it works with `{}` notation but not `[]`. I'm trying to read in a range.

Comment: Does this work for specifying range of years and months in the same fashion like "file:///your/path/data=mydata/year=[2015-2018]/month=[1-6]/day=[5-10]/*")

Comment: It's so strange that the second method is not implemented in pyspark. It would be really handy to have it.

Answer (score 7):

you need to provide `mergeSchema = true` option. like mentioned below (this is from 1.6.0):

```
val dataframe = sqlContext.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("file:///your/path/data=jDD")
```

This will read all the parquet files into dataframe and also creates columns year, month and day in the dataframe data.

Ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging

Comment: Schema Merging is only required if the schema's are different, if they are the same then you do not need this.

Comment: schema merging documentation for 3.3.2 https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging

Answer (score 1):

In my case with pyspark:

```
sdf_table = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket/table/**/*.parquet")
```

The ** is all partition of parquet (a glob expression )

note that read all files parquet in the bucket "table/" , so keep wwarning with other files

Comment: It is best solution without specifying all partition paths.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to use wildcards, like Cristian suggested. After some digging, I found the following that seems to work:

`spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").parquet("s3a://bucket/table/")`

https://kontext.tech/article/887/read-parquet-files-from-nested-directories

Answer (score 0):

The answers in this thread did not assist my similar need, and so I created [and subsequently answered] this question.

[Include partition steps as columns when reading Synapse spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73137428/include-partition-steps-as-columns-when-reading-synapse-spark-dataframe)