# Reading parquet files from multiple directories in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, parquet

I need to read parquet files from multiple paths that are not parent or child directories.

for example,

```
dir1 ---
       |
       ------- dir1_1
       |
       ------- dir1_2
dir2 ---
       |
       ------- dir2_1
       |
       ------- dir2_2
```

`sqlContext.read.parquet(dir1)` reads parquet files from dir1_1 and dir1_2

Right now I'm reading each dir and merging dataframes using "unionAll". 
Is there a way to read parquet files from dir1_2 and dir2_1 without using `unionAll` or is there any fancy way using `unionAll`

Thanks

Comment: Hi I am a similar task to read multipleJson files but the codes people provided here didnt work :(  did you find a solution?

Answer (score 67):

A little late but I found this while I was searching and it may help someone else...

You might also try unpacking the argument list to `spark.read.parquet()`

```
paths=['foo','bar']
df=spark.read.parquet(*paths)
```

This is convenient if you want to pass a few blobs into the path argument:

```
basePath='s3://bucket/'
paths=['s3://bucket/partition_value1=*/partition_value2=2017-04-*',
       's3://bucket/partition_value1=*/partition_value2=2017-05-*'
      ]
df=spark.read.option("basePath",basePath).parquet(*paths)
```

This is cool cause you don't need to list all the files in the basePath, and you still get partition inference.

Comment: When I just use this code, it is searching for the directories in /home/ directory, Can you please post the entire syntax?

Comment: @N00b when I tried this code, it gives me an error that load takes only 4 arguments but i have my  paths to 24 files.. is there an option to override this . I am trying not to do multiple loads and a union that is why i would like to use load to put multiple files to a df

Comment: Works perfectly for me! 
@EB, did you save it as a list and then run it as an expression `(*paths)` ?

Comment: Do you need the "*"? when I use it, it returns error.

Answer (score 16):

In case you have a `list` of files you can do:

```
files = ['file1', 'file2',...]
df = spark.read.parquet(*files)
```

Comment: * is the trick. When you are dealing with programs that generates list of dirs, this is most suitable way to read the value from that list vairable.

Answer (score 14):

Both the [parquetFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.parquetFile) method of `SQLContext` and the [parquet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet) method of `DataFrameReader` take multiple paths. So either of these works:

```py
df = sqlContext.parquetFile('/dir1/dir1_2', '/dir2/dir2_1')
```

or

```py
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/dir1/dir1_2', '/dir2/dir2_1')
```

Comment: None of these works for me. It finds "suspicious paths" and then gives me a long list of java stuff.

Comment: Happened to me too. You need to add an option:

     .option("basePath", "file:///your/path/")

as in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33656595/2851294

Answer (score 5):

For **ORC**

```
spark.read.orc("/dir1/*","/dir2/*")
```

spark goes inside dir1/ and dir2/ folder and load all the **ORC** files.

For Parquet,

```
spark.read.parquet("/dir1/*","/dir2/*")
```

Answer (score 4):

Just taking John Conley's answer, and embellishing it a bit and providing the full code (used in Jupyter PySpark) as I found his answer extremely useful.

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient
client = InsecureClient('http://localhost:50070')

import posixpath as psp
fpaths = [
  psp.join("hdfs://localhost:9000" + dpath, fname)
  for dpath, _, fnames in client.walk('/eta/myHdfsPath')
  for fname in fnames
]
# At this point fpaths contains all hdfs files 

parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet(*fpaths)


import pandas
pdf = parquetFile.toPandas()
# display the contents nicely formatted.
pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spark-Scala you can do this.

```
val df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("basePath", "s3://bucket/").csv("s3://bucket/{sub-dir1,sub-dir2}/")
```