# How to Union a bunch of parquet files together using Spark Map Reduce?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, parquet

I have a large number of parquet files in a directory that represents different tables of the same data schema and I want to merge them together into one big RDD. Ideally, I would like to do a map reduce where the mapper emits small RDD's and the reducer merges them. However, I couldnt figure out how to emit RDD's within a mapper. Any ideas?

The first line below generates the list of files in the directory and the second line should generate the complete RDD. However, it gives an unable to serialize error since I dont think you can create a RDD within a map instance.

```
arr = map(lambda x: ["/mnt/s3/rds/27jul2017-parquet/%s-%s-%s.parquet" % (x[0], x[1], x[2]), x[1].zfill(10), x[2].zfill(10)], map(lambda x: x.name.split('.')[0].split('-'), dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/s3/rds/27jul2017-parquet/')))   
result = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[1])      
sc.parallelize(arr).map(lambda x: (1, spark.read.parquet(x[0]))).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x.unionAll(y) )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37257709/647053

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading parquet files from multiple directories in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257111/reading-parquet-files-from-multiple-directories-in-pyspark)

Comment: also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257111/reading-parquet-files-from-multiple-directories-in-pyspark

Comment: Can you read multiple parquet files generated manually from different tables of the same schema and read them in like that? i will try

Comment: Yes, that worked. Looks like having multiple parquet files in one directory can be merged into a spark dataframe as long as it has the same schema

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifying a file in `spark.read.parquet` specify the directory, you'll get a dataframe (not an RDD) containing all the data:

```py
df = spark.read.parquet("/mnt/s3/rds/27jul2017-parquet/")
```

`map` iterates through the rows of your RDD to operate changes, it cannot load files if it could you'd end up with an RDD whose rows are dataframes...