# Read specific files and merge/union these schema evolutionized files into single Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark, and I'm trying to achieve the below problem.
**Scenario**
I am trying to read multiple parquet files (and csv files as well, if possible later on) and load them into single spark dataframe in Python for specific <strike>range of</strike> dates, I'll explain the condition for selecting the dates later.
Reason: Schema evolution - new columns added in the recent/latest partition, so Union is not possible or I'm unaware. If there is a way to do Union in *efficient* way, please let me know about that as well. 
Files look like this:

```
s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files/partition_date=2020-12-25/
# Partitions do not exist for weekend days, i.e., Saturday and Sunday
s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files/partition_date=2020-12-28/
s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files/partition_date=2020-12-29/
s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files/partition_date=2020-12-30/  # Consider this file with new columns in it
s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files/partition_date=2020-12-31/  # Consider this file with new columns in it
```

Parquet (and csv, for different folder) resides in each of these files look like this:

```
s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files/partition_date=2020-12-31/data_2020-12-31.parquet
```

Before schema changed, I used to load **everything** (all of the partitions) that existed in folder `s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files` and then inserting the data into single Spark dataframe using below:

```
spark_df = spark.read.format('parquet').load('s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files')
```

But now, I want to pull files just from specific dates, as specific range of dates won't work because of missing partitions. So I created the `list` using the `for` loop to just check which partitions exist. This list contains strings of all the dates for which partition exists.

```
dates = ['2020-12-25','2020-12-26','2020-12-27','2020-12-28','2020-12-29','2020-12-30','2020-12-31'] 
# I'll retrieve these dates by other efficient ways later on
existing_dates = []
# 'for' loop implementation
existing_dates = ['2020-12-25','2020-12-28','2020-12-29','2020-12-30','2020-12-31']
```

So here's the task for me:

1. I want to pull data *just for* dates that exist in `existing_dates`
2. I also need to **merge** partitions with new schema evolutionized partitions that contains new additional columns(namely: 2020-12-30 and 2020-12-31 in this example)
3. I need to *check* whether the partition-parquet-file is empty or not, too!
   I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49059234), but I don't know equivalent code in Pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use {} syntax to read specific partitions.

```py
base_path = 's3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files'

# Note 1: Extra {{ is to add literal {.
# Note 2: Reading by partitions removes the partition column (partition_date) in returned dataframe by default.
#         To keep the partition_date column, add basePath option to set your parquet data path.
df = (spark.read
      .option('basePath', base_path)
      .parquet(f'{base_path}/partition_date={{{",".join(existing_dates)}}}')

# f'{base_path}/partition_date={{{",".join(existing_dates)}}}' = 
# s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files/partition_date={2020-12-25,2020-12-28,...}
```

FYI, other syntax [] can do range capturing.

`s3://dir1/dir2/dir3/files/partition_date=2020-12-2[5-8]`

will capture partitions for 2020-12-25, 2020-12-26, 2020-12-27, 2020-12-28.

2. When you read partitions that missing columns and other partitions with additional columns, use `mergeSchema` option to align all columns.

```py
df = (spark.read
      .option('basePath', base_path)
      .option('mergeSchema', 'true') # this should handle missing columns
      .parquet(f'{base_path}/partition_date={{{",".join(existing_dates)}}}')
```

3. I am not sure what is the purpose of this yet. What would you like to do after identifying it? I am asking because depends on the task, you may not need to identify the empty parquet or not.

Comment: Thank you so much, @emma for your answer. I couldn't understand the `{{` and `literal .` as I'm encountering it first time. Could you please explain it to me? Also, 
1. Could I use it for the CSV file the same way by just replacing `parquet` to `csv` or is there any other hurdle?
2. If down the lane, schema is changed may be in this fashion: format of some columns, from `int` to `string` for newer files 
(i.e., `column x: int (nullable = true)` -> older files,
        `column x: string (nullable = true)` -> newer files)
Is there a way to do typecasting before the statement you provided?

Comment: In `f''` formatting string syntax, you use {variable} to put the variable's inserted.  So, the `{` character is a special character in side of format string.  Let's say I have a variable `name='world'`, and I want to make a string "hello world", I can do `f'hello {name}'`.  I wrap the variable with `{}` and the value is inserted there. 
Now if I want to get a string "hello {world}", I need to insert the literal "{" character. Since "{" is a special character in format string, I need to escape it. To escape the "{", you add another "{". Try printing `f'hello {{`, it should results in "hello {"

Comment: So to get "hello {world}", you need `f'hello {{{name}}}`.  The middle `{name}` will be replaced with "world" and you have literal { and } on each side.

Comment: For the 2nd question, if you have `int` in some partition and `string` in another partition, in this case `mergeSchema` cannot handle the 2 different data types and spark will crash. You need to read only old partitions and fix it to string and save it.

Comment: Understood, thanks Emma!