# Reading multiple directories into multiple spark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read a list of directories each into its own dataframe. E.g.

```
dir_list = ['dir1', 'dir2', ...]
df1 = spark.read.csv(dir_list[0])
df2 = spark.read.csv(dir_list[1])
...
```

Each directory has data of varying schemas.

I want to do this in parallel, so just a simple for loop won't work. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Please refer the below post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257111/reading-parquet-files-from-multiple-directories-in-pyspark

Comment: But I want to keep the data in separate dataframes, so doing `spark.read.csv(*dir_list)` will not work (puts them all in one df).

Comment: what do you mean by "I want to do this in parallel" ? can you elaborate more and why you want it to be in parallel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is :))

"How" will depend on what kind of processing you do after read, because by itself the `spark.read.csv(...)` won't execute until you call an action (due to Spark's lazy evaluation) and putting multiple reads in a `for` loop will work just fine.

So, if the results of evaluating multiple dataframes have the same schema, parallelism can be simply achieved by `UNION`'ing them. For example,

```
df1 = spark.read.csv(dir_list[0])
df2 = spark.read.csv(dir_list[1])
df1.withColumn("dfid",lit("df1")).groupBy("dfid").count()
   .union(df2.withColumn("dfid",lit("df1")).groupBy("dfid").count())
   .show(truncate=False)
```

... will cause both `dir_list[0]` and `dir_list[1]` to be read in parallel.

If this is not feasible, then there is always a [Spark Scheduling](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) route:

> Inside a given Spark application (SparkContext instance), **multiple
> parallel jobs can run simultaneously if they were submitted from
> separate threads.** By “job”, in this section, we mean a Spark action
> (e.g. save, collect) and any tasks that need to run to evaluate that
> action.