# Reading Parquet file with Pyspark returns java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Conflicting directory structures detected. Suspicious paths

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to load parquet files in the following directories:

```
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-1
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-2
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-3
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-4
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-5
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-6
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-7
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-8
```

This is what I wrote in Pyspark

```py
s3_bucket_location_of_data = "s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/"
df = spark.read.parquet(s3_bucket_location_of_data)
```

but I received the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o109.parquet.
: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Conflicting directory structures detected. Suspicious paths:
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-1
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-2
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-3
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-4
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-5
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-6
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-7
    s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/marketplace_id-8
```

After reading other StackOverflow posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257111/reading-parquet-files-from-multiple-directories-in-pyspark), I tried the following:

```
base_path="s3://dir1/" # I have tried to set this to "s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/" as well, but it didn't work
s3_bucket_location_of_data = "s3://dir1/model=m1/version=newest/versionnumber=3/scores/"
df = spark.read.option("basePath", base_path).parquet(s3_bucket_location_of_data)
```

but that returned a similar error message as above. I am new to Spark/Pyspark and I don't know what I could possibly be doing wrong here. Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Try with `spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", True).parquet(s3_bucket_location_of_data)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the detailed path. Just load the files from the base_path.

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://dir1")
df.filter("model = 'm1' and version = 'newest' and versionnumber = 3")
```

The directory structure is already partitioned by 3 columns, model, version and versionnumber. So read the base and filter the partition, then you could read all the parquet files under the partition path.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry about delay in my response (was traveling and just got back)! Your suggestion is very interesting; however, `"s3://dir1"` has A LOT of data and thus, this line `df = spark.read.parquet("s3://dir1")` will just fail to complete (error out). I have given up and decided to use `union` to concatenate them using `for` loop...