# Pyspark- Read specific partitions by range

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to read in a specific partition range using pyspark. I have seen various posts such as as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650421/reading-dataframe-from-partitioned-parquet-file), that when using scala you can do the following:

```
val dataframe = sqlContext
  .read
  .parquet("file:///your/path/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/day={5,6}/*")

val dataframe = sqlContext
  .read
  .parquet("file:///your/path/data=jDD/year=2015/month=10/day=[5-10]/*")
```

When using pyspark, the first method using `{}` brackets works, this reads in specific partitions. However, I can't get the range method using `[]` to work.

I'm wondering is the syntax different for pyspark or is it just not supported?

Comment: Could your share which range you are trying exactly. The syntax is correct and it is supported by pyspark as it just passes it to JVM as is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036343/5986661 does this: `sc.textFile("/my/dir1,/my/paths/part-00[0-5]*,/another/dir,/a/specific/file")`