# How to concatenate./append multiple parquet files in PySpark with the same schema

Tags: pyspark, parquet

I have multiple parquet files in the form of - `file00.parquet`, `file01.parquet`, `file02.parquet` and so on. All the files follow the same schema as `file00.parquet`.
How do I add the files one below the other, starting from `file00` onwards in that same order using PySpark?

Comment: Do you want to read all the parquet at the same time?

Comment: @Jonathan Reading them  same time or one by one is not the main issue for me now. The files are all in the same directory. I want to read all those parquet files and save them to one single parquet file/dataframe using Pyspark. I had done the same using pandas, but I don't want to use pandas as it takes too much time for large files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append multiple parquet files to one dataframe in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164709/how-to-append-multiple-parquet-files-to-one-dataframe-in-pandas), [Reading DataFrame from partitioned parquet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650421/reading-dataframe-from-partitioned-parquet-file), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240979/how-can-i-read-multiple-parquet-files-in-spark-scala

Comment: This also answers another question I had, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that all parquet files are in the same directory and they have the same schema, then you can read all the parquet by:

```
file_0_path = /root/to/data/file00.parquet
file_1_path = /root/to/data/file01.parquet
....

df = spark.read.parquet("/root/to/data/")
```

If you want to save them in a single parquet, you can:

```
df.repartition(1).write.save(save_path, format='parquet)
```

Comment: So the read.parquet will read all the files from that folder will read all the files in that order automatically? That is interesting. I will try this out! Thank you.
My main goal is to convert the final parquet file to a .hyper type file. This will be very helpful to concatenate them all into one single parquet file before conversion.

Comment: @AshishPadhi Yes you can because your current directory structure is exactly the same of how partitioning work. If you want to make sure that your record is ordered, you better use `orderBy()` before you write the new parquet.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the following error:

`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.parquet.`

There are more messages in the error, but I am not able to copy paste the whole thing here.

Comment: Hi @AshishPadhi, could you edit your own post or open a new post? It's impossible to debug your error based on this error log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73316032/error-in-reading-multiple-parquet-files-with-same-schema-with-pyspark
I have made a new post.