# Include partition steps as columns when reading Synapse spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have the following partition strategy in an ADLS Gen2 store

```
dir_parquet = "abfss://blah.windows.net/container_name/project=cars/make=*/model=*/*.parquet"
```

And this would load in the already partitioned data into a dataframe accordingly. I am aware of using the `.filepath(n)` in SQL to achieve this, and effectively require the same thing but in a notebook dataframe.

How can I keep the `project`, `make` and `model` values in the dataframe as separate columns?

According to [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650421/reading-dataframe-from-partitioned-parquet-file) setting `.option("mergeSchema","true")` on read would work however it did not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I received no answer to this and cannot find an official means to do so, I wrote the below code.

People with this problem may also find recursively returning blob directories to be useful and if so please see the `deep_ls` function [here](https://www.rakirahman.me/directory-recursion-synapse/) (not my code).

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from typing import List

def load_dataframes_with_partition_steps(dir_urls:List[str]) -> List[pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame]:
    """
    Written by: Paul Wilson, 2022-07-29

    Takes in a list of blob directories including their partition steps and returns a list of dataframes with the associated
    partition steps in the in the dataframe.

    Ex. input...:
        ['abfss://container@yourgen2store.dfs.core.windows.net/projects/cars/make=Vauxhall/model=Astra/transmission=Manual',
            'abfss://container@yourgen2store.dfs.core.windows.net/projects/cars/make=Ford/model=Fiesta/transmission=Automatic']

    ...which is turned into a list of dicts...
        [{'url': 'abfss://container@yourgen2store.dfs.core.windows.net/projects/cars/make=Vauxhall/model=Astra/transmission=Manual',
        'make': 'Vauxhall',
        'model': 'Astra',
        'transmission': 'Manual'},
        {'url': 'abfss://container@yourgen2store.dfs.core.windows.net/projects/cars/make=Ford/model=Fiesta/transmission=Automatic',
        'make': 'Ford',
        'model': 'Fiesta',
        'transmission': 'Automatic'}]

    ...and from that list a list of dataframes per url and associated partition steps, such as:
        [df1, df2, ..., dfn]
    """

    def load_dataframe(url:str=None, partition_steps:dict={}, file_format:str=None, df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame=None) -> pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame:
        """
        Recursively load a dataframe and apply the partition steps via withColumn
        """
        if file_format is None or len(file_format) == 0:
            raise(ValueError('file_format must not be none, the URL must end in the file format (.parquet, .csv, etc)'))

        # if there is a url and non empty partition steps without a df loaded then load the dataframe
        if (url is not None and len(partition_steps.keys()) > 0 and df is None):
            df = spark.read.format(file_format).load(url)

            # df is loaded so do not pass a url indicating it is loaded
            return load_dataframe(url=None, partition_steps=partition_steps, df=df)

        # if here then the df is loaded and proceed to apply withColumn
        if (url is None and df is not None and len(partition_steps.keys()) > 0):

            # load the first item in the partition steps dict
            key = list(partition_steps.keys())[0]
            value = list(partition_steps.values())[0]

            # remove the first item from the partition steps dict
            partition_steps.pop(key)

            # load the dataframe with the new partition step
            df = df.withColumn(key, F.lit(value))
            return load_dataframe(url=None, partition_steps=partition_steps, df=df)

        # if it makes it here then the dataframe is loaded and the partition steps are applied
        return df

    # list of dataframe dict values of url and partition steps
    list_df_dicts = list()

    if not isinstance(dir_urls, list):
        raise TypeError('dir_urls must be a list of string values')

    # iterate over all urls and generate dict of partition values
    for url in dir_urls:

        # dict to store url and partition steps
        d_dict = dict()
        d_dict['url'] = url

        # get the format from the last part of the url
        file_format = url.split('.')[-1]
        d_dict['file_format'] = file_format

        # split the url keeping only partition steps (ex. make=Vauxhall)
        url_split = [u for u in d_dict['url'].split('/') if '=' in u]

        if len(url_split) == 0:
            raise ValueError('The list of URLs must contain the partition steps, ex. make=ford')

        # turn the partition=item into a key:value
        partition_items = [u.split('=') for u in url_split]

        # iterate over every item in partition_items=[['key', 'value']] and set dict[key] = value
        for item in partition_items:
            key = item[0]
            value = item[1]
            d_dict[key] = value

        list_df_dicts.append(d_dict)

    # iterate over all the dicts and load the dataframes to a list with their partition steps in place
    list_dfs = list()
    for d_dict in list_df_dicts:

        # get the url from the d_dict
        url = d_dict['url']

        # get the format
        file_format = d_dict['file_format']

        # remove the url from the d_dict
        d_dict.pop('url')
        df = load_dataframe(url=url, partition_steps=d_dict, file_format=file_format)
        list_dfs.append(df)

    # return the list of dataframes
    return list_dfs
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add a base path to the call:

```
val dataFrame = sparkSession.read
  .option("basePath", path)
  .parquet(path + "/day=*/hour=*/platform=*/*.parquet")
```

If I do not add the base path I won't have the columns day/hour/platform. I do with the option.

[This article](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/wildcard-path-partitions/read) kind of explain why it is not working without, but actually forgot that you can add it manualy.

Comment: I have not tried this but will give it a go and revert! Thanks.